# Capture FlashWindowEx event of a running process

Tags: c#, winapi, events

I have an app that is already running - every now and then it triggers a FlashWindowEx event (the windows 7 icon flashes). I would like to capture this event but I can't seem to find any good info on how.

My thoughts were that it would go like this:

- Hook into running process using Process.GetProcessesByName
- Set up event handler for FlashWindowEx
- Catch it and do whatever

I guess my question is:

Is this possible?

1. Is there a way to get a list of available events from a running process?
2. How would I hook into FlashWindowEx?

Comment: I go into tunnel vision and miss the icons flashing at me (Instant messages, etc). So I thought capturing it and displaying a more *prominent* message would be nice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The `WH_SHELL` hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644991%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) notifies you when a window is flashing. According to the documentation:

- `nCode` = `HSHELL_REDRAW`
- `wParam` = the handle of the window
- `lParam` = `TRUE` if the window is flashing, `FALSE` otherwise.