# winapi minimized window notification (orange flushy)

Tags: c, winapi

I'm using the Win32 API and I want to check if a minimized window is flashing, ie showing the window tab with orange, blinking color, through C code.

I checked the API and I only found [**FlashWindow/Ex**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679347.aspx), which is causing the flashing; however I want to test it against a specific window.

I also found `SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT,..)`, which may be related, but also global, I suppose.

I'm using Windows 7

Comment: Clear indications of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @IInspectable, my application handles a number of opened windows. Each one of these can use `FlushWindow` at any point and my application works like an automaton and handles stuff -- one focused window at a time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capture FlashWindowEx event of a Running Process (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785334/capture-flashwindowex-event-of-a-running-process-c)

Comment: @user6096479: it is **flash**, not **flush**.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes i know, i typed wrongly in the comment but correctly on my question, thanx :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Win32 API function to query if a given window is currently being flashed with `FlashWindow/Ex()`.

However, [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990.aspx) has a [`WH_SHELL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644991.aspx) hook, which reports `HSHELL_REDRAW` notifications when a window title is redrawn:

> nCode [in]
>   Type: int
>
> The hook code. If `nCode` is less than zero, the hook procedure must pass the message to the `CallNextHookEx` function without further processing and should return the value returned by `CallNextHookEx`. This parameter can be one of the following values.
>
> ...
>
> HSHELL_REDRAW
>   6
>   The title of a window in the task bar has been redrawn.

> wParam [in]
>   Type: WPARAM
>
> This parameter depends on the value of the `nCode` parameter, as shown in the following table.
>
> ...
>
> HSHELL_REDRAW
>   A handle to the redrawn window.

> lParam [in]
>   Type: LPARAM
>
> This parameter depends on the value of the `nCode` parameter, as shown in the following table.
>
> ...
>
> HSHELL_REDRAW
>   The value is TRUE if the window is flashing, or FALSE otherwise.

So, you can use [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522.aspx) to get the thread ID of the target window, and then pass that to the `dwThreadId` parameter of `SetWindowsHookEx()` to start monitoring all windows in the same thread as the target window, and then you can filter for `HSHELL_REDRAW` notifications to detect if the target window is flashing or not.

Comment: oh i see, thanx

Comment: @zett42, i saw that answer, thanx. Do you mean i can hook my only application and still receive system events and `HSHELL_REDRAW` as well? (and not every other window? i mean hooking)

Comment: @user6096479 See parameter `dwThreadId` of `SetWindowsHookEx`